# How to after clicking color or size, the price will not change in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product

[image]

[image]

I changed the product price by javascript. But after I click on color or Size, the product price displays the original product price. I don't wanna be like that, please someone please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
'use strict';
return function (widget) {
    var updatePrice = $("#wallpaper_attribute").val();
    var globalOptions = {
        productId: null,
        priceConfig: null,
        prices: {},
        priceTemplate: '<span class="price"><%- data.formatted %>/m²</span>'
    };

    $.widget('mage.priceBox', widget, {
        options: globalOptions,
        onUpdatePrice :function onUpdatePrice(event, prices) {
        if (updatePrice == '1') {
            return this;
        }else{
            return this.updatePrice(prices);
        }
        
        },
        

    });
    return $.mage.priceBox;
}
```

price-box-mixin.js

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box': {
            'Magepow_Wallpaper/js/price-box-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
```

requirejs-config.js
I used to intervene in the price-box.js file and handle it like that. You can learn more in Magento_Catalog / js / price-box of magento to

Comment: thanks for working for me